# No image in my google image search

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-image-search

Ok, so I want to use the google api for image search, I know is deprecated, but I don't want to use the custom search

This is the code I've been using

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('search', '1');

  var imageSearch;

  function addPaginationLinks() {

    // To paginate search results, use the cursor function.
    var cursor = imageSearch.cursor;
    var curPage = cursor.currentPageIndex; // check what page the app is on
    var pagesDiv = document.createElement('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < cursor.pages.length; i++) {
      var page = cursor.pages[i];
      if (curPage == i) { 

      // If we are on the current page, then don't make a link.
        var label = document.createTextNode(' ' + page.label + ' ');
        pagesDiv.appendChild(label);
      } else {

        // Create links to other pages using gotoPage() on the searcher.
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href="/image-search/v1/javascript:imageSearch.gotoPage("+i+');';
        link.innerHTML = page.label;
        link.style.marginRight = '2px';
        pagesDiv.appendChild(link);
      }
    }

    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    contentDiv.appendChild(pagesDiv);
  }

  function searchComplete() {

    // Check that we got results
    if (imageSearch.results && imageSearch.results.length > 0) {

      // Grab our content div, clear it.
      var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
      contentDiv.innerHTML = '';

      // Loop through our results, printing them to the page.
      var results = imageSearch.results;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        // For each result write it's title and image to the screen
        var result = results[i];
        var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
        var title = document.createElement('div');

        // We use titleNoFormatting so that no HTML tags are left in the 
        // title
        title.innerHTML = result.titleNoFormatting;
        var newImg = document.createElement('img');

        // There is also a result.url property which has the escaped version
        newImg.src="/image-search/v1/result.tbUrl;"
        imgContainer.appendChild(title);
        imgContainer.appendChild(newImg);

        // Put our title + image in the content
        contentDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
      }

      // Now add links to additional pages of search results.
      addPaginationLinks(imageSearch);
    }
  }

  function OnLoad() {

    // Create an Image Search instance.
    imageSearch = new google.search.ImageSearch();

    // Set searchComplete as the callback function when a search is 
    // complete.  The imageSearch object will have results in it.
    imageSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

    // Find me a beautiful car.
    imageSearch.execute("Ferrari");

    // Include the required Google branding
    google.search.Search.getBranding('branding');
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

The problem is that when I run it, the images doesn't appear

I know that the problem is that the url it is using doesn't work

The problem is this line of code

```
newImg.src="/image-search/v1/result.tbUrl;"
```

But I don't know if there is other url I can use or what can I do

And I can't use JQuery, this for a College Proyect, and we can't use JQuery

Thanks for your Atention!

Comment: Are you using the id they give you? Some codes we copy and paste have a generic id that needs to be replaced.

Comment: I have the same issue. No result displayed. When I display log I don't have any result in `imageSearch.results`

Comment: the XHR call on GimageSearch return `callback google.search.ImageSearch.RawCompletion('1', null, 403, 'This API is no longer available.', 200)` I think we can not use this API

Answer (score 0):

The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011 and apparently totally stop.

the XHR call on GimageSearch return `callback google.search.ImageSearch.RawCompletion('1', null, 403, 'This API is no longer available.', 200)`

You must use the new custom-search API : https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
link.href="/image-search/v1/javascript:imageSearch.gotoPage("+i+');';
```

to

```
link.href="javascript:imageSearch.gotoPage("+i+');';
```

And change

```
newImg.src="/image-search/v1/result.tbUrl;"
```

to

```
newImg.src=result.tbUrl;
```

Comment: I tried that for the updated (?) "V1", to no effect. I don't get any image either, with the "hello world" example they give at https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide

Comment: Why the downvote? After applying the above changes, the code works. Provide your code, if the changes do not have any effect for you.